# HTTP headers in the php://input

Tags: php, nginx

I've got a live site to which many devices are connecting. The protocol is based on XML and in PHP I've used reading the 'php://input' stream to parse the XML. This goes fine in 99.9999% of the cases, but sometimes the HTTP headers before the XML data. This happens only once every million requests or so, but it does irritate me that it keeps happening.

We are using nginx 1.9.11 and PHP 7.0. Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Is a word missing in your explanation:  "... but sometimes the HTTP headers before the XML data ...". How does it look like? You got the headerdata infront the php://input stream?

Comment: Maybe there is a bug in your program. Maybe you are sometimes sending the headers as POST data. I doubt that anyone will give you a clear answer.

Comment: Are these POST or GET requests or even different? Which HTTP headers appear in those rare cases exactly?

Comment: The headers are always the same, and it is for PUT requests. It is a bug in some part of the whole cycle, but I can't determine where. It might be the device itself, HAProxy or nginx that causes this behaviour.